# Parallel processing in R using SQL databases

Tags: sql, r, parallel-processing, bioconductor

I am trying to run a permutation analysis using the clusterProfiler bioconductor R package. To exemplify my problem I will use an example in the manual which I adapted to run in parallel:

```
library(clusterProfiler)
library(doMC)
library(foreach)

data(geneList, package="DOSE")
PermNumber <- 10000
registerDoMC(15)  #change the 2 to your number of CPU cores  
ggoList <- NULL
ggoList  <- foreach(lo=1:PermNumber) %dopar% {
    print(lo)
    gene <- names(geneList)[abs(geneList) > 2]
    gene.df <- bitr(gene, fromType = "ENTREZID",
            toType = c("ENSEMBL", "SYMBOL"),
            OrgDb = org.Hs.eg.db)
gene}
```

While this works fine without parallel-loops, a following error appears in a parallel loop:

> Error in { : task 2 failed - "database disk image is malformed"

I have found a similar problem in some forums, but none of them in R or clusterProfiler. As far I understood, the problem is occurring probably due to SQL database that `bitr` uses (is hard to implement parallel processing in SQL). Any idea to surpass this problem?

Comment: You said `While this works fine without loops,...`. Could you try to this with `%do%` instead of `%dopar%`? I'm wondering if your problem is with loop-execution or **parallel**-loop execution.

Comment: @ChiPak, You are right. However, the my point is how to run the expression within the loop in parallel.

Comment: Please clarify. Does it work with loop-execution?

Comment: This only does not work when in parallel.

Comment: Hi @user3081668 if my answer helped you to solve your issue please consider accepting as an answer by clicking on the check mark to the left. This lets the community know the answer worked.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find `doMC` so I used `parallel` and `doParallel` instead. `doMC` should work but try with `parallel` also.

```
library(parallel)
library(doParallel)
registerDoParallel(detectCores()) # this detects number of cores on system
```

*Note that I had to download the `OrgDb` separately*. (You probably already downloaded this.)

Ok, I didn't receive the same `error` as you, but the following still worked for me:

```
ggoList  <- foreach(lo=1:PermNumber, .packages="clusterProfiler") %dopar% {
            print(lo)
            gene <- names(geneList)[abs(geneList) > 2]
            gene.df <- bitr(geneID = gene, 
                            fromType = "ENTREZID",
                            toType= c("ENSEMBL", "SYMBOL"),
                            OrgDb = "org.Hs.eg.db")
            gene}
```

I think your problem might occur because you need to export `clusterProfiler` to each core, in order for `bitr` to work in each core. I exported `clusterProfiler` using `.packages="clusterProfiler"` in the code above. Test with `PermNumber <- 2` before trying with a larger number.